# File upload using dojo.io.iframe.send creates obnoxious download prompt in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm encountering an issue with uploading files using the send method native to dojo.io.iframe in which it prompts me to download something from the URL I am sending a file or blob of data to, while immediately following up with any further calls. I can't duplicate this issue on Internet Explorer or Chrome, but it's recurring on Firefox 7.0.1.

I can provide demo code on request.